# How to send query strings to view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, query-string

I am in an odd situation. My MVC application communicates with a server using Oauth. In a controller action the application communicates with a Oath provider to get Access Token. The Oauth server accepts a callback URL which can contains only /controller/action */Test/TestAction* no query strings. when the Oath sends back the user to callback URL (/Test/TestAction) it has lost the query strings. I tried to save them in Session before calling the Oauth server, but how do I send them to the View in TestAction?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the ViewBag?

Comment: Yes, I can not use ViewBag, I am sorry because I didn't formulate my question well. becuase the query strings are used in a javascript file.

Comment: Does your query string params correspond to your action parameters? Or is it purely used client-side?

Comment: They are purely used client-side.

Comment: So you simply want to tack the query string onto the end of the current URL?

Comment: Thanks you I got an idea, I can save them in hidden fields and access them from javascript.

Comment: If you are using MVC, it's best to go the MVC way and have your action accept those parameters and pass them down to your view. That way before you make your OAuth request you can temporarily store your data e.g. `TempData` and then pull them out and redirect back to the same action. This should allow you to pass the same data to the view & give you the original URL as well.